# How to load and initialize a class/jar/... at runtime even if it is out of the classPath?

Tags: java, url, reflection, classloader

I want to initialize a class that is not known during compilation (yet implementing a known interface).

So I tried something like this :

```
Class<?> cls = class.foreName("NotKnown",true,ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

It worked in Eclipse , but as a runnable jar file I found out this won't work because it won't load a class which is out of your classPath.

How can I make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new classloader that would load classes from the folder where your new class is located:

```
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { ... });
Class<?> cls = cl.loadClass("NotKnown");
```

I.e. if you have a class `foo.bar.Baz` and it was compiled to `/someFolder/foo/bar/Baz.class`, you should use `new File("/someFolder").toURI().toURL()` as a folder to load your class from.